# Time Machine stopped working

Tags: backup, time-machine, disk-utility

I have an iMac running High Sierra version 10.13.6. Attached via the USB port is a 4 TB HDD with a 1 TB partition I use for backups. I've been using Time Machine with the TimeMachineEditor app for almost a year now and its been working fine. Using TimeMachineEditor I have a backup scheduled for once a week. A day or so ago the scheduled backup failed and I can't seem to get it to work.

My earlier backups have been running around 140 MB and I have almost 300 MB on my backup drive. When I go to Time Machine Preferences I get a window like the one shown below.

[image: TM_001]

The blue circle is used to indicate the red message circle. When I click on the red circle I get the following message:

[image: TM_003]

I've run Disk Utility/First Aid on my TimeMachine backup drive and it appears to be ok. Below is an image of the First aid result.

[image]

When Disk Utility sees this drive it reports the following:

[image]

**Can anyone explain what happened and why time machine will not finish the backup.**

Comment: I can't make this an answer because it's too anecdotal - but I had so many issues with HS & TM that updating to Mojave just 'fixed'.

Comment: My machine is not Mojaveable? Mojave-able?, Mojavable?

Comment: Ah, OK... then my only 'solution' would be clone your boot drive, reformat to HFS+ & copy the clone back. Forget APFS on HS, it's a nightmare [but again, that's only anecdotal... see my Question history here for the full story]

Comment: Wow.  That sucks and ends my 5 years of Time Machine use. I decided to use Backblaze as my new backup plan.  Any comment of this plan would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tetsujin  You mentioned a link that you did not include in your 2nd comment. You referred to your Question history for the full story but I don't know how to get there

Comment: Just click my name at the end of any comment.